# Android - How to show a GIF for a limited time?

Tags: android, gif, animated-gif

I have an `Android` application that shows a screen with an animated `GIF` image while it's loading. **The image gets displayed forever or shown only a blank screen if I use a timer**. I just want to show it for 5 seconds. **How can I  displaying the `GIF` only by 5 seconds?**

**With this code the image gets displayed forever:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public GifImageView gifImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.GifImageView);
    gifImageView.setGifImageResource(R.drawable.gif2);
}
```

}

**With this code the gif image is not shown only a blank screen is shown but after 5 seconds the application closes:**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public GifImageView gifImageView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    gifImageView = (GifImageView) findViewById(R.id.GifImageView);
    startCountDownTimer();
}

private void startCountDownTimer() {
    new CountDownTimer( 5000, 5000 ) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            gifImageView.setGifImageResource(R.drawable.gif2);
        }
        public void onFinish() {
            finish();
        }
    }.start();
}
```

}

Here is the GifImageView code:

```
public class GifImageView extends View {

private InputStream mInputStream;
private Movie mMovie;
private int mWidth, mHeight;
private long mStart;
private Context mContext;

public GifImageView(Context context) {
super(context);
this.mContext = context;
}

public GifImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public GifImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
this.mContext = context;
if (attrs.getAttributeName(1).equals("background")) {
    int id = Integer.parseInt(attrs.getAttributeValue(1).substring(1));
    setGifImageResource(id);
}
}


private void init() {
setFocusable(true);
mMovie = Movie.decodeStream(mInputStream);
mWidth = mMovie.width();
mHeight = mMovie.height();
requestLayout();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
setMeasuredDimension(mWidth, mHeight);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
long now = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
if (mStart == 0) {
    mStart = now;
}

if (mMovie != null) {
    int duration = mMovie.duration();
    if (duration == 0) {
        duration = 1000;
    }

    int relTime = (int) ((now - mStart) % duration);
    mMovie.setTime(relTime);
    mMovie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
    invalidate();
}
}

public void setGifImageResource(int id) {
mInputStream = mContext.getResources().openRawResource(id);
init();
}
```

Comment: How does the `GIF` get displayed indefinitely? When you launch the second `activity` the first one is no longer visible, so the `GIF` is not visible.

Comment: No, with this code the gif image is displayed indefigally, I need is that after 5 seconds, the activity ends or stops, how can I do that?

Comment: *...with this code...* - which code you are referring to?

Comment: @Gourav the question contained code before editing.

Comment: Then why you removed it?

Comment: Have you tried the answers?

Comment: I do not know who removed it, now I can not load the code again

Comment: Have you tried my answer?

Comment: I have already updated the code ...

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `CountDownTimer`, set the time to `5000 milliseconds`. When `onFinish()` is called you can stop displaying the `GIF`. Use this code:

```
new CountDownTimer(5000, 5000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        // You don't need to use this.
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        // Put the code to stop the GIF here.
    }

}.start();
```

You can read more about `CountDownTimers` in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

Comment: I have placed the **CountDownTimer**, but the gif image is not shown, only a blank screen appears, but **yes** the application closes after 5 seconds

Answer (score 0):

With what @AmeerTaweel told, you can use a `CountDownTimer`. Another simple approach would be to use a `Handler` for that in the `onCreate()` method like this:

```
new Handle().postDelayed(new Runnable(
    @Override
    public void run() {
        ImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE); //Or the GIF View
    }
), 5000); //5 sec
```